# How to Spam Filter Gmail Messages by Recipient Address?

Tags: filter, google-apps-script, gmail, spam

I use the dot feature (m.yemail@gmail.com instead of myemail@gmail.com) to give emails for questionable sites so that I can easily spot spam from my address being sold.

I made this function and set it to trigger every 30 minutes to automatically filter these.

```
function moveSpamByAddress(){
  var addresses = ["m.yemail@gmail.com"]
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var ii = 0; ii<messages.length; ii++){
      for (var iii = 0; iii<addresses.length; iii++){
        if (messages[ii].getTo().indexOf(addresses[iii]) > -1){
          threads[i].moveToSpam()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but I noticed that this runs slower than I would expect it to (but my expectation may be unreasonable) given that my inbox only contains 50 messages and I am only currently filtering one address. Is there a way to increase execution speed?

Also are there any penalties for running scripts too often? I see that I have the option to trigger a script every minute, and that would increase the likelihood of filtering a message before I see it, but it would also run the scripts uselessly significantly more times.

Comment: Just a hint - you can use the `+` notation in Gmail to 'tag' your emails, giving you a little more control than just adding a period. `myemail+ANYSTRING@gmail.com` will always send messages to `myemail@gmail.com`.

Comment: isn't there already a filter feature in gmail?

Comment: @admdrew Unfortunately some websites don't accept emails with the + notation. I have not run into any issues with periods yet.

Comment: @Fabricator yes there is, however they do not allow you to send things to spam unless I am missing something. You can skip the inbox entirely, add labels, delete, and all sorts of other things, but sending to spam does not appear to be available.

Comment: In that case, it would much easier to tag them with gmail filter, and then use script to move them to spam.

Comment: @MarcB I prefer consecutive i multiples for nested loops and sequential letters for multiple top level loops if more specific names aren't being used for overall consistency.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using native gmail filters plus apps script.
Script time quotas varies from 1 to 6 hours depending on account type.
To improve performance, first check getInboxUnreadCount and return inmediately if zero.
If you use a 1minute trigger, make sure to use a lock to avoid one timer starting while the other runs. If the lock is in use simply return.

First, make a gmail filter so when "to" matches your special address, apply a special label like "mySpam"
Second, make an apps script with my suggestions above, plus your code no longer needs to search so much, now you just need to find emails with that label (a single api call) and .moveToSpam

There shouldnt be that many at any time in the label if the script runs often.

Comment: I will add those two suggestions thank you. About the native filters. I looked for a long time on how to do this and could not find it. Could you be more specific? I am not talking about creating a custom spam label, skipping the inbox (archiving), or deleting the filtered messages. This seemed like an obvious feature to be included so I was surprised when I did not find it.

Comment: aha, I see, Gmail filters do not have a "mark as spam" action. I will update my answer